# log4j2 not creating a rolling

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I had an application working with log4j1. The configuration I have in the log4j.properties is working fine and it creates the file for log.

I migrate to log4j2 and now the file is not created, even though I follow the documentation. I try all the different solutions here but I can't make it work.

This is my log4j2.xml inside resources in my application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="MyApp" packages="">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="tmp/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

This is the dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tired changing the path of my file with the full path, changing the folder in case it was permissions problem.

I don't have any error, but when the application runs I don't see any file.
I even print 2 versions of log4j; log4j and log4j2. Log4j creates the file no problem, log4j2 don't

this is my file for log4j

log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Appender1,Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.File=/tmp/info.log
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} - logger1 - %-5p %c %m%n
log4j.appender.Appender1.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.Appender1.maxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.Appender1.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=/tmp/errors.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %c %m%n
log4j.appender.Appender2.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.Appender2.maxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.Appender2.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

I'm new to this, can anybody help me with this?
what am I'm missing?

let me know if you need more information.

edit: adding the whole pom file in case something is wrong with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.6
 

com.software
seguros
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
seguros
Administracion de seguros

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/eu.hansolo.enzo/Enzo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.hansolo.enzo</groupId>
        <artifactId>Enzo</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.6</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 1.2.17 jar and add the log4j-api and log4j-core jars. It will solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I added the dependencies but still no luck I don't know why.
I will upload the whole pom file in case there is something wrong there.